# Postgres query: array_to_string with empty values

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I am trying to combine rows and concatenate two columns (name, vorname) in a Postgres query.

This works good like this:

```
SELECT nummer, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(name|| ', ' ||vorname), '\n') as name
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          nummer, name, vorname
   FROM   myTable
   ) AS m
GROUP  BY nummer 
ORDER  BY nummer;
```

Unfortunately, if "vorname" is empty I get no results although name has a value.

Is it possible get this working:

```
   array_to_string(array_agg(name|| ', ' ||vorname), '\n') as name
```

also if one column is empty?

Comment: Years later, I just want to say a big 'thank you'. This only came up recently in a project. Saved my life.

Comment: great to hear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use coalesce to convert NULL values to something that you can concatenate:

```
array_to_string(array_agg(name|| ', ' ||coalesce(vorname, '<missing>')), '\n')
```

Also, you can concatenate strings directly without collecting them to an array by using the string_agg function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 9.1, then you can use third parameter for array_to_string - null string

```
array_to_string(array_agg(name), ',', '<missing>') from bbb
```